# Reading from csv file and printing as organized table

Tags: python-3.x

[Picture stating what needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6wGx.png)

[Picture showing what format it needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOZZE.png)

I've got an assignment due regarding reading from a csv file and printing it as a organized table.

I have so far achieved the following code which prints the code in a string fomat which will also be shown below.

```
import csv

table = ''
with open('geek-music.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames]))
    for row in reader:
        table_row = '<tr>'
        for fn in reader.fieldnames:
            table_row += '<td>{}<\td>'.format(row[fn])
        table_row += '<\tr>'
        table += table_row
```

When using this code I receive the following:

```
[['Track', 'Artist', 'Album', 'Time'], ['Computer Love', 'Kraftwerk', 'Computer World', '7:15'], ['Paranoid Android', 'Radiohead', 'OK Computer', '6:27'], ['Computer Age', 'Neil Young', 'Trans', '5:24'], ['Digital', 'Joy Division', 'Still', '2:50'], ['Silver Machine', 'Hawkwind', 'Roadhawks', '4:39'], ['Start the Simulator', 'A-Ha', 'Foot of the Mountain', '5:11'], ['Internet Connection', 'M.I.A.', 'MAYA', '2:56'], ['Deep Blue', 'Arcade Fire', 'The Suburbs', '4:29'], ['I Will Derive!', 'MindofMatthew', 'You Tube', '3:17'], ['Lobachevsky', 'Tom Lehrer', 'You Tube', '3:04']]
```

After further editing of my code I have resulted with the following:

```
import csv


f = open("geek-music.csv",'r')

for aline in f:
    values = aline.split(',')
#    print(values[0])
    Track = [values[0]]
    Artist = [values[1]]
    Album = [values[2]]
    Time = [values[3]]

    data = list(zip(Track, Artist, Album, Time))
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
            line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(12) for x in d)
            print(line)
            if i == 0:
                print('-' * len(line))

f.close()
```

This however results in the following:

```
Track       |Artist      |Album       |Time

---------------------------------------------------
Computer Love|Kraftwerk   |Computer World|7:15

------------------------------------------------------
Paranoid Android|Radiohead   |OK Computer |6:27

-------------------------------------------------------
Computer Age|Neil Young  |Trans       |5:24

---------------------------------------------------
Digital     |Joy Division|Still       |2:50

---------------------------------------------------
Silver Machine|Hawkwind    |Roadhawks   |4:39

-----------------------------------------------------
Start the Simulator|A-Ha        |Foot of the Mountain|5:11

------------------------------------------------------------------
Internet Connection|M.I.A.      |MAYA        |2:56

----------------------------------------------------------
Deep Blue   |Arcade Fire |The Suburbs |4:29

---------------------------------------------------
I Will Derive!|MindofMatthew|You Tube    |3:17

------------------------------------------------------
Lobachevsky |Tom Lehrer  |You Tube    |3:04

---------------------------------------------------
```

This is very close to what I am looking for except that it is still quite far from what is shown in the image above.

Comment: So what's the problem? We can help you figure out why code you've written isn't acting like you expect, but we can't do your assignment for you.

Comment: @glibdud can you please check the second link I have posted as that shows which format it should be in. I just want some guidance on what low level Python code I should be using as texttables seems a little overkill/complicated

Comment: Unfortunately, SO isn't a tutorial service. We can't really provide general "guidance". Give it a shot, and if you reach a point where you're stuck on something that's not doing what you expect, then you can ask a question about that specific issue and you'll likely get a better response. This question as written falls under the "too broad" category.

Comment: @glibdud Searched around stackoverflow and learnt some new techniques, however it is still quite far from what is expected. Any tips?